# Stop rearranging tag order

Tags: feature-request, tags

Not sure if this has been addressed before on any of the Stack Exchange sub sites, but while it seems that tag order on asked questions is ruled by how popular each is, some people organise tag order based on largest/most dependent system, down.

Personally, can't see much of an advantage to users viewing the questions, either way around, so would like to suggest this gets changed.

Comment: What would be the point apart from creating unnecessary work for the devs? Why would you care about the tag order, does it affect anything?

Comment: Interesting comment... Not sure why someone would write up a question, unless they cared about something. I care because a problem with [/windows /timezone /parted-magic /rdesktop](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78614/custom-linux-timezone), can be considered different from a problem with `/`[tag:parted-magic] `/`[tag:rdesktop] `/`[tag:timezone] `/`[tag:windows]

Comment: Yes, apparently you care but I don't see how it makes a difference, so I don't understand _why_ you care, that's why I asked. Why the snarky tone? I'm trying to understand what you are asking to see if I can help. Anyway, I still don't understand how the order of the tags affects anything. As far as I can tell the tags are sorted in the order you added them in. Newer tags on the right, first tag added on the left. There is no implied hierarchy in the tags, they are all equal, so their order does not carry any meaning. I therefore ask again, why do you care what order the tags are in?

Comment: I know ?we? have had this issue before, but wasn't thinking snarky/sarcastic (What, after re-reading my comment, first comes to mind, as being the most likely tone, without any in-person cue's) when wrote my reply, I just thought it was a logical deduction. Perhaps we can ignore the perceived tone going forward, and just address the Q&A instead?

Comment: Happily. I still don't understand what makes you think that the order of the tags is informative. As far as I can tell (I just tested on an old question of mine) tags are kept in the order you put them in, there is no rearrangement occurring. Even if they were rearranged however, the order does not imply importance so I still don't understand what you're asking for here. You _seem_ to be asking that the tags be left in the order you chose for them which is what already happens by default. I am honestly not trying to be difficult here, I just don't understand what you're asking for or why.

Comment: I am not sure if I can better explain the principle, than my last comments on the issue, perhaps if you think about (in that example) which OS is connecting to the other (forgetting the subject matter of the sub-site this question was posted on, for principle realization). However, I have just realised I made a mistake in what metric tags are ordered by (at least for me)... It is [how popular the tags are](http://i.imgur.com/UkNjMHj.png) / http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97045 (This makes sense now, after getting more sleep last night)

Comment: So, you're saying that you add tags A,B,C and these are rearranged into B,C,A in order of tag popularity? I haven't noticed that but perhaps it does happen. What both slm in his answer and I are saying is that it doesn't matter. Nobody looks at the order of the tags, there is no hierarchy involved so it really does not matter.

Comment: Not sure if you saw it, but there was a screenshot embedded in "how popular the tags are", that shows what order I put them in prior to submitting the question. "Doesn't matter" is rather subjective, and it brings me back to my "Not sure why someone would write up a question, unless they cared about something". I do appreciate you speaking for me (and possibly many other community members), but *I* (for one) *look at this*, as clues to tell what the asker is, well, asking.

Comment: Also, per my question, if there are some that don't notice the order, but some that do, unless there is some overbearing disadvantage, why not do it for those that it matters to?

Answer (score 4):

Since I've been using the site I've never thought the tags were organized in any fashion beyond them being relevant for a particular question. The tags are purely for categorization purposes, and probably wouldn't expect anything more from them than this.

Comment: Ah, hover over them going from left-to-right, on most sub-sites, to see where I get my impression from. I can see other uses for them, that I don't think breaks existing known-to-me functionality (Why not?), hence the suggestion.